# Biber - How to remove a period between title and titleaddon?

Tags: biblatex, biber

The referencing style mandated by my university stipulates that online resources should be denoted as follows:

*"Title of the book/article"* [online].

Note that there is no period between the title and the titleaddon.
At the moment I am trying to satisfy the requirement by using titleaddon, but I do not know how to remove the period.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{dialogue}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings,shadows,patterns}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{censor}
    %\StopCensoring 

\usepackage[top=3.50cm, bottom=3.40cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
\usepackage[hidelinks, breaklinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[affil-it ]{authblk}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear-ibid, sorting=nty, urldate=long, dateabbrev=false, maxbibnames = 8,maxcitenames=2,mincitenames=1,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{urlseen = {Accessed }
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{stephen2012theRoleOfCultureInResearch,
    author = {David Stephens},
    title = {The Role of Culture in Interpreting and Conducting Research},
    titleaddon = {[online]},
    booktitle = {Research Methods in Educational Leadership and Management},
    editor = {Ann Briggs, and Marianne Coleman, and Marlene Morrison},
    date = {2012},
    edition = {3},
    publisher = {SAGE Publications},
    pages = {46-60},
    url = {https://ebookcentral.proquest.com/lib/nottingham/detail.action?docID=4004042},
    urldate = {2020-05-16},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `biblatex-ext` styles have a command for that: `\titleaddonpunct`. So you only need

```
\renewcommand*{\titleaddonpunct}{\addspace}
```

and are good to go.

If all `titleaddon`s you are ever going to use are of the "[online]" persuasion and set in square brackets, I would remove the square brackets from the field and add them via the field format.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear-ibid,
  sorting=nty,
  maxbibnames = 8, maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1,
  giveninits=true,
  urldate=long, dateabbrev=false,]{biblatex}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\renewcommand*{\titleaddonpunct}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  urlseen = {Accessed},
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{stephen2012theRoleOfCultureInResearch,
  author     = {David Stephens},
  title      = {The Role of Culture in Interpreting and Conducting Research},
  titleaddon = {online},
  booktitle  = {Research Methods in Educational Leadership and Management},
  editor     = {Ann Briggs and Marianne Coleman and Marlene Morrison},
  date       = {2012},
  edition    = {3},
  publisher  = {SAGE Publications},
  pages      = {46-60},
  url        = {https://ebookcentral.proquest.com/lib/nottingham/detail.action?docID=4004042},
  urldate    = {2020-05-16},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Stephens, D. (2012). “The Role of Culture in Interpreting and Conducting Research” [online]. In: Research Methods in Educational Leadership and Management. Ed. by A. Briggs, M. Coleman, and M. Morrison. 3rd ed. SAGE Publications, pp. 46–60. url: https://ebookcentral.proquest.com/lib/nottingham/detail.action?docID=4004042 [Accessed May 16, 2020].]

---

Note that names in the `author` and `editor` field must be separated only with `and` not with `, and`. `editor = {Ann Briggs, and Marianne Coleman, and Marlene Morrison},` is wrong and should be

```
editor = {Ann Briggs and Marianne Coleman and Marlene Morrison},
```

Usually `hyperref` is the last package to be loaded. There are only a few exceptions of packages that must be loaded after `hyperref`. `biblatex` is not one of them.

Comment: Thank you for a complete and informative answer. Where could I find the list of packages that must be loaded after ```hyperref```? I tried to search the package manual, but I was not successful.

Comment: @NikoZ. Usually the package you have to load after `hyperref` would mention it in its documentation. (So there is no convenient single location to look this up.) There is a list on this site, though, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/35864